# setTargetFragment for android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I am trying to pass info from a `DialogFragment` to it's hosting `Fragment`, but the problem is I am using the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of the regular `android.app.Fragment` package for my `Fragments`.

This code gives me an error:

```
messageResponseDialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
```

`setTargetFragment` is expecting a `Fragment` and not a `support.v4.Fragment`.

**How can I do implement a callback from the DialogFragment to the hosting Fragment using the android.support.v4.app.Fragment?**

Comment: try using the support v4 version of the DialogFragment instead of the regular one and it should work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are trying to set a target fragment from a `DialogFragment` that is not from the `android.support`

**solution:**

change your DialogFragment to `android.support`